# Get data JSON to file html with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

i have file process.php and file html.
i need to send data from process to html.

example i got data a=target. i want to send it to input in file html. so when process is success, it will send `value="target"` to input.

my code in process.php :

```
$myObj->data-f1 = $target_path;

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
echo $myJSON;
```

and this file.html with ajax

```
<script>
    var gol = $(this).data('f1');
    $("#filepdf").val(gol);
</script>

<input id="filepdf" value="" />
```

im use modal for html.
example my code working for that script is like this:

```
$row=array();

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))
{
    array_push($row,"<button
                        data-toggle='modal'
                        data-xname='$row[name]'
                        data-target='#myHP'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></button>");
$rows[] = $row;

}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

i can call data-xname to ajax with `var name=$(this).data('xname')`
but in this is different condition.

Comment: Do you understand that this is a __mess__? I have this, I have that. Read please [mcve].

Comment: i though i have describe the problem.. i just send some code because to answer why im use this code. if comparison is not allowed, i will delete it.